# Cron based scheduler in python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I have a python app that runs every one hour and needs to perform some scheduled tasks based on some DB configuration. For example, a configuration may be:

- Do X every day at 15:00
- Do Y every Monday at 8:00

I'ts ok to have up to one hour of delay.

I can implement this myself, but I wonder if there's an out-of-the-box solution, something like [APScheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), but that is not running all the time.

Comment: If you were on linux/unix, you would use `cron` for this.

Comment: @John1024 I know, but I want my app's users to be able to schedule tasks themselves. So I need the scheduling plan to be in the DB.

Comment: Can your software include a cron task that reads the DB configuration and performs accordingly?  Many apps do this just by placing a file during installation into `/etc/cron.hourly`.

Comment: @John1024 thanks. Unfortunately no, I can't do that. My app is a Django app that runs on the cloud, so I don't have access to cron files. I can schedule cron-like tasks to trigger my app every X hours/minutes.

Answer (score 0):

APScheduler seems like a good choice as well, but if you want to simply invoke your python app every:

```
  Do X every day at 15:00
  Do Y every Monday at 8:00
```

Why not just have the cron job run your script by making your script executable with chmod +x and then adding

```
     0 0 */2 * * /path/to/your/pyScript.py
```

with the `-e` flag invoked.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to store the scheduled tasks in the DB, so my app's users will be able to schedule tasks themselves (it's a Django app).

Comment: In that case APScheduler might be easier to programmatically to schedule tasks, but you shouldn't have any problems creating a line in linux-cron based off of user features, I've had to do this a couple of times in Ruby and Java and it wasn't too bad. Please let me know if you have any questions!